# How do I get VS to instal multiple items under the same start menu program

Tags: visual-studio

Thank you for taking the time to answer this. I'm working in Visual Studio Community 2017 and I have two applications I've made that need to be installed under Author Tools in the Start Menu (Win 10). Shown Below

Author Tools/SGM Conversion
Author Tools/Graphic Conversion

I've tried going to the Publish Options window and creating a Product name and keeping the Assembly name "Author Tools" but it still installs under a different start menu name.

Thank you for the help.
Max

Answer (score 0):

If I have the same publisher name all the programs will be installed under it. :-)